# Assign characters 'æ', 'ø', or 'å' in C

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, char

So I have a variable `char c` that I want to assign `'å'` to. If I try `c = 'å'` I get a warning in the terminal that says: `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`

1. What is a multi-character constant?
2. How can I assign either `'æ'`, `'ø'`, or `'å'` to a `char c`?

Comment: This would depend on your codepage.  If you need to store Unicode characters, then you need to be using `wchar_t` instead of `char`.

Comment: `multi-character character constant` that's just bad wording. It means "multi-char character literal assigned to a single char. The value has been truncated, creating gibberish".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is a multi-character constant?

This indicates that your text editor is using more than one byte to store characters in the source code file, possibly because it is saving it as a Unicode character in UTF-8 encoding.  Since `char` can only hold one byte, your compiler is telling you that this assignment won't have the intended effect because you are trying to store a multi-byte literal into a variable that can only hold one byte.

> How can I assign either `'æ'`, `'ø'`, or `'å'` to a `char c`?

This depends on multiple factors.  `char` can store values from 0 to 255.<sup>1</sup>  Only 0 to 127 are defined in ASCII; 128 to 255 are only defined in some other code pages (for example, ISO-8859-1).  In order to store one of these characters in a `char` you must do the following:

1. Configure your text editor to save using a code page that uses one byte for each character *and* that contains the characters you want to store.
2. Configure your compiler to read the source file using this code page.  (With gcc for example this would be `-finput-charset=...`.)
3. If the program outputs these characters (to standard output or to a file!) then whatever is reading the output will also have to be informed of this code page so that it knows how to process bytes in the 128 to 255 range.

If there is a mismatch between any of these three then you will likely see compiler warnings or garbage output where the characters should be.

You can skirt around most of these problems by using *wide characters* (`wchar_t`), which are typically big enough to store any Unicode code point.  You will still have to make sure that your text editor and compiler are in agreement regarding the encoding of characters in the source, unless you make use of the `\uNNNN` Unicode escape sequence, which can represent any Unicode code point in C source code by using only ASCII-compatible characters (which means that the compiler doesn't have to be informed what code page the source code is in).

---

<sup>1</sup> Or -128 to 127; the default signed-ness of `char` is unspecified by the C standard, but since we are talking characters I am going to assume that 0 to 255 is the intended range.

Comment: And then the characters were in NFD. Damnit.

Answer (score 2):

A multi-character-constant is a literal `int`, uses the character-literal-syntax with more than one `char`, and has an implementation-defined value.

Avoid them, unless you are really sure you want them, want to tie your code to your implementation and know they do what you want..
Even then, a saner and less error-prone way is just creating the `int`-constant you want from `char`-literals and operators explicitly.

Why do you have that error even though you only see one character?

Because character means different things to different people, depending on their mood and the phase of the moon:

- Byte (Often also octet, though that's not a synonym in any way, especially in C).
- Unicode codeunit.
- Unicode codepoint.
- Unicode Grapheme.
- Symbol in some other character-set.

Your current trouble stems from using a character-set where that symbol is not a single C-`char`, namely UTF-8.
If you insist on assigning them to a single `char`, select a character-set having them as single bytes.
Otherwise, properly use a string of `char`s.

BTW: Using `wchar_t` might be used as a band-aid, though multiple-codeunit codepoints are still possible with UTF-16 (and you are more likely to keep a bug with them there), and even UTF-32 has multiple-codepoint graphemes).

Answer (score 1):

These chars are not in ASCII table. `char` has size of 1 byte, however encoding of those characters takes more than 1 byte, hence your compiler warns you about it. You probably will have to use a `wchar_t` type and specific to this type functions.

Comment: And how do I use `printf` on wchar_t variables?

Comment: `printf("text");` for char, `wprintf(L"text");` for wchar_t

Comment: `wchar_t` is not a panacea, though it may be a band-aid in this case.

Comment: `char` can take other characters in a non-ASCII single-byte code page.

Comment: You know, one byte could be plenty big enough for any UTF-32 codepoint.